# .NET 8 new authorisation end points causing strange behaviour no response data on login ie token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

In .NET 8, the authentication code as changed dramatically for Web API. The authentication call `AddApiEndpoints` adds a whole load of default login points, one being a `POST` method with this json body:

```
{
    "email": "string",
    "password": "Test12345!",
    "twoFactorCode": "string",
    "twoFactorRecoveryCode": "string"
}
```

which I submit as

```
{
    "email": "myemail@email.com",
    "password": "Test12345!",
    "twoFactorCode": "string",
    "twoFactorRecoveryCode": "string"
}
```

Now I do get login fine on the Web API side, but there is no response data, it just returns 200 ok?

[image]

When I did this before in other versions it would send back the JWT token so that the user can use it in swagger here.

So my question is how do I get the bearer token to appear here for the user in the response so they can select it and put it into the authorise text field.

[image]

```
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultScheme = "Identity.Bearer"; // this is the default scheme to be used
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Identity.Bearer";
 }).AddCookie("Identity.Bearer")
 // we configure JWT bearer authentication here

.AddJwtBearer("bearer", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000"; // URL of Identity Server; use IConfiguration instead of hardcoding 
    options.Audience = "client.mydomain.com"; // ID of the client application; either hardcoded or configureable via IConfiguration if needed 
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true; // require HTTPS (may be disabled in development, but advice against it)
    options.SaveToken = true; // cache the token for faster authentication
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true; // get more details on errors; may be disabled in production 
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(setup =>
        {
            // Include 'SecurityScheme' to use JWT Authentication
            var jwtSecurityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                Name = "JWT Authentication",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Scheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                Description = "Put **_ONLY_** your JWT Bearer token on textbox below!",

                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                }
            };

            setup.AddSecurityDefinition(jwtSecurityScheme.Reference.Id, jwtSecurityScheme);

            setup.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    { jwtSecurityScheme, Array.Empty<string>() }
});

        });
```

Also why has the API create to login end points a get and a post?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modify this part:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultScheme = "Identity.Bearer"; // this is the default scheme to be used
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Identity.Bearer";
 }).AddCookie("Identity.Bearer")
 // we configure JWT bearer authentication here

.AddJwtBearer("bearer", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000"; // URL of Identity Server; use IConfiguration instead of hardcoding 
    options.Audience = "client.mydomain.com"; // ID of the client application; either hardcoded or configureable via IConfiguration if needed 
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true; // require HTTPS (may be disabled in development, but advice against it)
    options.SaveToken = true; // cache the token for faster authentication
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true; // get more details on errors; may be disabled in production 
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Now you would reveive the  accesstoken & refresh token in response:

[image]

Comment: When u say modify do u mean script the entire code ? to that one line

Comment: Happy Days that worked why did they add the 2fa extra bits in the jason body dont understand that though